# Contents of android permission groups

Tags: android, permissions

Android has different permission groups and permissions. Each permission group represents certain permissions. But I couldn't find a list of permissions held by each group. Is it published anywhere?

For eg. android.permission.ACCOUNT_MANAGER is associated with permission group ACCOUNTS. 
I need a list of such associations.

Comment: I agree, it seems like Google should maintain a list of this information documented on their website. Along with the protection level for each permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to use PackageManager getAllPermissionGroups() and queryPermissionsByGroup()
to enumerate the entire Android permission hierarchy. The code below produced the output shown at the end on a 5.1.1 (SDK 22) device. The groups marked "personal" have groupInfo.flags == 1, and appear to correspond to the permission groups that are called "dangerous" in Marshmallow.

You will get different permission hierarchies on different devices due to differences in SDK levels and the fact that apps can define custom permissions.

```
/**
 * Uses PackageManager getAllPermissionGroups() and queryPermissionsByGroup()
 * to enumerate the Android permission hierarchy.
 */
private void showPermissionTree()
{
    final PackageManager pm = m_context.getPackageManager();
    if (pm == null)
        return;

    /*
     * Get a list of all permission groups and sort them alphabetically.
     * Then add to the end of the list the special case of a null group name. There can be
     * numerous permissions that are not listed under a group name.
     */
    List<PermissionGroupInfo> groupInfoList = pm.getAllPermissionGroups(0);
    if (groupInfoList == null)
        return;

    ArrayList<String> groupNameList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (PermissionGroupInfo groupInfo : groupInfoList) {
        String groupName = groupInfo.name;
        if (groupName != null) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
                /*
                 * SDK 17 added the flags field. If non-zero, the permission group contains
                 * permissions that control access to user personal data.
                 * N.B. These are the permissions groups that are called "dangerous" in
                 * Marshmallow.
                 */
                if (groupInfo.flags != 0) {
                    groupName += " (personal)";
                }
            }
            groupNameList.add(groupName);
        }
    }

    Collections.sort(groupNameList);
    groupNameList.add(null);

    /*
     * Loop though each permission group, adding to the StringBuilder the group name and
     * the list of all permissions under that group.
     */
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(10000);
    final String INDENT = "   ";

    for (String groupName : groupNameList) {
        if (groupName == null)
            groupName = "null";

        sb.append("* ").append(groupName).append("\n");

        ArrayList<String> permissionNameList = getPermissionsForGroup(groupName);
        if (permissionNameList.size() > 0) {
            for (String permission : permissionNameList) {
                sb.append(INDENT).append(permission).append("\n");
            }
        } else {
            sb.append(INDENT).append("no permissions under group\n");
        }

        sb.append("\n");
    }

    m_textView.setText(sb.toString());
}


/*
 * Gets and returns a list of all permission under the specified group, sorted alphabetically.
 *
 * N.B. groupName can be null. The docs for PackageManager.queryPermissionsByGroup() say
 * "Use null to find all of the permissions not associated with a group."
 */
private ArrayList<String> getPermissionsForGroup(String groupName)
{
    final PackageManager pm = m_context.getPackageManager();
    final ArrayList<String> permissionNameList = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        List<PermissionInfo> permissionInfoList =
                pm.queryPermissionsByGroup(groupName, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
        if (permissionInfoList != null) {
            for (PermissionInfo permInfo : permissionInfoList) {
                String permName = permInfo.name;
                if (permName == null) {
                    permName = "null";
                } else if (permName.isEmpty()) {
                    permName = "empty";
                }
                permissionNameList.add(permName);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        // e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d(TAG, "permissions not found for group = " + groupName);
    }

    Collections.sort(permissionNameList);

    return permissionNameList;
}
```

```
* android.permission-group.ACCESSIBILITY_FEATURES
   no permissions under group

* android.permission-group.ACCOUNTS (personal)
   no permissions under group

* android.permission-group.AFFECTS_BATTERY
   android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE
   android.permission.FLASHLIGHT
   android.permission.TRANSMIT_IR
   android.permission.VIBRATE
   android.permission.WAKE_LOCK

* android.permission-group.APP_INFO
   android.permission.GET_TASKS
   android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES
   android.permission.MANAGE_ACTIVITY_STACKS
   android.permission.PERSISTENT_ACTIVITY
   android.permission.REAL_GET_TASKS
   android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED
   android.permission.REMOVE_TASKS
   android.permission.REORDER_TASKS
   android.permission.RESTART_PACKAGES

* android.permission-group.AUDIO_SETTINGS
   android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS

* android.permission-group.BLUETOOTH_NETWORK
   android.permission.BLUETOOTH
   android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN
   android.permission.BLUETOOTH_MAP
   android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED

* android.permission-group.BOOKMARKS (personal)
   no permissions under group

* android.permission-group.CALENDAR (personal)
   no permissions under group

* android.permission-group.CAMERA (personal)
   no permissions under group

* android.permission-group.COST_MONEY
   no permissions under group

* android.permission-group.DEVELOPMENT_TOOLS
   android.permission.ACCESS_ALL_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
   android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION
   android.permission.DUMP
   android.permission.READ_LOGS
   android.permission.SET_ALWAYS_FINISH
   android.permission.SET_DEBUG_APP
   android.permission.SET_PROCESS_LIMIT
   android.permission.SIGNAL_PERSISTENT_PROCESSES
   android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS
   com.android.chrome.permission.DEBUG

* android.permission-group.DEVICE_ALARMS (personal)
   no permissions under group

* android.permission-group.DISPLAY
   android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW

* android.permission-group.HARDWARE_CONTROLS
   android.permission.ACCESS_FM_RADIO
   android.permission.ACCESS_MTP
   android.permission.HARDWARE_TEST
   android.permission.MANAGE_USB

* android.permission-group.LOCATION (personal)
   no permissions under group

* android.permission-group.MESSAGES (personal)
   no permissions under group

* android.permission-group.MICROPHONE (personal)
   no permissions under group

* android.permission-group.NETWORK
   android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
   android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE
   android.permission.ACCESS_WIMAX_STATE
   android.permission.BROADCAST_NETWORK_PRIVILEGED
   android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE
   android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE
   android.permission.CHANGE_WIMAX_STATE
   android.permission.CONNECTIVITY_INTERNAL
   android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION
   android.permission.INTERNET
   android.permission.LOOP_RADIO
   android.permission.NFC
   android.permission.READ_WIFI_CREDENTIAL
   android.permission.RECEIVE_DATA_ACTIVITY_CHANGE
   android.permission.SCORE_NETWORKS
   com.android.vending.BILLING
   com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE
   com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE
   com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND
   com.google.android.gtalkservice.permission.SEND_HEARTBEAT
   com.google.android.permission.BROADCAST_DATA_MESSAGE
   com.google.android.xmpp.permission.BROADCAST
   com.google.android.xmpp.permission.SEND_RECEIVE
   com.google.android.xmpp.permission.USE_XMPP_ENDPOINT
   com.google.android.xmpp.permission.XMPP_ENDPOINT_BROADCAST
   com.gsma.services.nfc.permission.TRANSACTION_EVENT

* android.permission-group.PERSONAL_INFO (personal)
   no permissions under group

* android.permission-group.PHONE_CALLS (personal)
   no permissions under group

* android.permission-group.SCREENLOCK (personal)
   no permissions under group

* android.permission-group.SOCIAL_INFO (personal)
   no permissions under group

* android.permission-group.STATUS_BAR
   android.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR

* android.permission-group.STORAGE (personal)
   no permissions under group

* android.permission-group.SYNC_SETTINGS
   android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS
   android.permission.READ_SYNC_STATS
   android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS

* android.permission-group.SYSTEM_CLOCK
   android.permission.SET_TIME_ZONE

* android.permission-group.SYSTEM_TOOLS
   android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS
   android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION
   android.permission.ACCESS_PDB_STATE
   android.permission.ASEC_ACCESS
   android.permission.ASEC_CREATE
   android.permission.ASEC_DESTROY
   android.permission.ASEC_MOUNT_UNMOUNT
   android.permission.ASEC_RENAME
   android.permission.BATTERY_STATS
   android.permission.BLUETOOTH_STACK
   android.permission.BROADCAST_PACKAGE_REMOVED
   android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY
   android.permission.CHANGE_BACKGROUND_DATA_SETTING
   android.permission.CLEAR_APP_CACHE
   android.permission.DIAGNOSTIC
   android.permission.FORCE_STOP_PACKAGES
   android.permission.GET_APP_OPS_STATS
   android.permission.GET_DETAILED_TASKS
   android.permission.GET_PACKAGE_SIZE
   android.permission.GLOBAL_SEARCH
   android.permission.GLOBAL_SEARCH_CONTROL
   android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS
   android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
   android.permission.MANAGE_USERS
   android.permission.MODIFY_APPWIDGET_BIND_PERMISSIONS
   android.permission.MOUNT_FORMAT_FILESYSTEMS
   android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS
   android.permission.NET_ADMIN
   android.permission.NET_TUNNELING
   android.permission.OEM_UNLOCK_STATE
   android.permission.READ_DREAM_STATE
   android.permission.READ_SEARCH_INDEXABLES
   android.permission.RECOVERY
   android.permission.REMOTE_AUDIO_PLAYBACK
   android.permission.SET_ANIMATION_SCALE
   android.permission.SET_PREFERRED_APPLICATIONS
   android.permission.SET_SCREEN_COMPATIBILITY
   android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER_COMPONENT
   android.permission.START_ANY_ACTIVITY
   android.permission.START_TASKS_FROM_RECENTS
   android.permission.SUBSCRIBED_FEEDS_READ
   android.permission.SUBSCRIBED_FEEDS_WRITE
   android.permission.WRITE_APN_SETTINGS
   android.permission.WRITE_DREAM_STATE
   android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS
   com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT
   com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT
   com.android.launcher3.permission.READ_SETTINGS
   com.android.launcher3.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS
   com.google.android.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS
   com.google.android.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS
   com.motorola.permission.ACCESS_COGRADIO

* android.permission-group.USER_DICTIONARY (personal)
   no permissions under group

* android.permission-group.VOICEMAIL (personal)
   no permissions under group

* android.permission-group.WALLPAPER
   android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER
   android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER_HINTS

* android.permission-group.WRITE_USER_DICTIONARY
   android.permission.WRITE_USER_DICTIONARY

* com.google.android.gms.permission.CAR_INFORMATION
   com.google.android.gms.permission.CAR_FUEL
   com.google.android.gms.permission.CAR_MILEAGE
   com.google.android.gms.permission.CAR_VENDOR_EXTENSION

* null
   no permissions under group
```

Answer (score 1):

Android permissions are listed [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html) and permission groups [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission_group.html). And then can also take a look at [PemissionInfo()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PermissionInfo.html).

Comment: I need which permission is associated with which permission groups. I have already seen those links.

Comment: Use `PermissionInfo()` and in result struct you got `public String group`: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PermissionInfo.html#group

Comment: Yeah, but I would need to write an app to iterate through permissions and get the associated groups. I am asking, is such a list of associations published anywhere?

Comment: Sorry, I do not know that. But what a problem to write any dumb app to do that and spit results out to logcat?

Comment: Of course I could write an app to do that. I wanted to know if there is any such being maintained already. I had got the output, now I have got time to put it here. I will add it also as my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is the list that I made on ICS. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0As7-0Nfn2fUTdEpXdHJIZVlUNWljb1RwTXVtREthSEE&single=true&gid=0&output=html

Answer (score 0):

Google does gives you the information on permission and permission group association.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview#perm-groups

In Android Studio Terminal you get the information with this command:

```
adb shell pm list permissions -s
```

The result is something like:

```
    All Permissions:
    
Microphone: record audio

SMS: read your text messages (SMS or MMS), receive text messages (WAP), receive text messages (MMS), receive text messages (SMS), send and view SMS messages, read cell broadcast messages

This app can provide content to Bixby Home cards.: Provide Bixby Home card content, Read Bixby Home data
```

Be aware to request all permissions your app needs. Things working correctly do not mean it will keep working in future. Permissions may be moved from one group into another, so don't rely on the current state:

> Caution: Future versions of the Android SDK might move a particular permission >from one group to another. Therefore, don't base your app's logic on the >structure of these permission groups.
>
> For example, READ_CONTACTS is in the same permission group as WRITE_CONTACTS as >of Android 8.1 (API level 27). If your app requests the READ_CONTACTS >permission, and then requests the WRITE_CONTACTS permission, don't assume that >the system can automatically grant the WRITE_CONTACTS permission.